# How to delete between year-week range?

Tags: postgresql

Imagine there are some data in Postgres table `mytable`:

| year | (iso) week |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 50 |
| 2021 | 51 |
| 2021 | 52 |
| 2022 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022 | 52 |
| 2023 | 1 |
| 2023 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023 | 24 (current week) |

I need to delete records that are between (2021, 51) and (2023, 1). It means that expected result should be:

| year | (iso) week |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 50 |
| 2023 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023 | 24 (current week) |

What sql-query could filter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### According to my experimental suggestion the below one will work

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (year > 2021 AND year < 2023)
   OR (year = 2021 AND week >= 51)
   OR (year = 2023 AND week <= 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by combining the year and the week, converting them to integers, and then apply a standard where :

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (year, week) IN
(
  select year, week
  from (
    select *, concat(year, to_char(week, 'fm00'))::int as yearWeek
    from mytable
  ) as s
  where yearWeek between concat(2021, to_char(51, 'fm00'))::int 
                       and
                       concat(2023, to_char(1, 'fm00'))::int
)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MOvbrXj7)